# System.NullReferenceException Solucionar

Tags: c#, asp.net

otra cosa de C#

Yo en core, tengo un modelo de tabla donde tengo una ForenigKey a otra tabla:

Tabla Producto:
`Id | NameProduct`

Tabla Shopp:
`Id | Foreingkey("Id_producto")`

Más o menos es así.

Cuando itero sobre la tabla Shopp -> puedo acceder a:
`Shopp.Id_Product -> Genial porqué está almacenado en la tabla` 
`Shopp.Producto.Name -> Me devuelve valor null`

¿Por que? ¿No se supone que el contexto de Datos de Shopp, debe de traerme esos datos y poder mostrarlos?

Gracias amigos!

Según la estructura con el Core de ShoppingCart es:

```
public class ShoppingCart
{   
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string User_Id { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int Product_Id { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Según estructura Modelo con Product es:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NameProduct { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }
    public ProductStatus ProductStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Y el código donde intento acceder al nombre del prodcuto es:

```
namespace EShopOS.Web.Client.OrdersFiles
         {
    public partial class OrderDetail : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        ApplicationDbContext context = null;
        ProductManager productManager = null;
        ShoppingCartManager shoppingCartManager = null;
        Product productos = null;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Traemos el contexto de los datos de producto capa de datos
            context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            shoppingCartManager = new ShoppingCartManager(context);
 
            var products = productManager.GetAll();

            //Almacenamos el usuario que está logueado
            string userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var carts = shoppingCartManager.GetAll().Where(u => u.User_Id == userId).Include(u => u.User);
           
            foreach(var cart in carts)
            {
                txtEmail.Text = cart.User.Email;
                txtIdCart.Text = cart.User_Id;
                txtProductId.Text = cart.Product_Id.ToString();
                txtProductName.Text = cart.Product.NameProduct;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muestra tu diagrama de tablas y la relacion que hay entre estas

Comment: Hola Japv, actualicé el comentario. No sé donde puedo ver el diagrama de tablas en visual. Así que te paso el modelo de la tabla de shopping. Hago foreach en la tabla de Shopping me reconoce "cart.Product.Name" que pertenece a la otra tabla, pero me trae valor null. No sé si me hace falta algún <List>

Comment: No debería ser Producto.NameProduct según tu estructura?

Comment: Si efectivamente así, es la estructura, espera un minuto y lo actualizo, con lo real.

Comment: Bueno actualicé con lo que estoy intentando hacer, creo que me falta traer los datos de product. Pero sinceramente, no se me ocurre como hacerlo.

Comment: Yo diría que tu error está en el método `shoppingCartManager.GetAll()`. porque no estás cargando los datos de `Product`. Por qué `Include(u=>u.User)` y no `Include(sc=>sc.Product)`? Date una vuelta [por aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/ef/core/querying/related-data/) para más información acerca de como cargar datos relacionados.

Comment: Voy a verlo Arriel! Gracias! Es una asignatura, que me está resultando complicada. Mil gracias :)

Comment: Ese era el problema?

Comment: Hola Arriel, estoy en ello aún, efectivamente por ahí viene el problema, como no controlo mucho de C#, me está costando resolver. Ya que sé que tengo que traerme el contexto de Product, pero aún estoy intentando ver como enlazarlo. Ahora mismo estoy probando con un Iqueryable ...

Comment: var carts = shoppingCartManager.GetAll().Where(u => u.User_Id == userId).Include(sc => sc.User); Así, si que me traigo el User_Id, pero el Product no

Comment: pero puedes poner tantos include como quieras, `var carts = shoppingCartManager.GetAll().Where(u => u.User_Id == userId).Include(sc => sc.User).Include(pr => pr.Producto).ToList();`

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera Genial!! Ahora a ver si puedo, blindear una lista, como ya os digo, tengo 0 destreza con este lenguaje ;)

Answer (score 0):

primero Mil gracias por vuestras aportaciones. Para mi han sido de gran ayuda, todas. Aprendí mucho. Bien, ya lo he solucionado.
Añadí una variable, donde me traigo los productos de la siguiente manera:
`var pdListo = shoppingCartManager.GetAll().Where(u => u.User_Id == userId).Include(sc => sc.User).Include(pr => pr.Product);`

y luego con un foreach, coloco la información en :

```
`  foreach (var pdr in pdListo) {
            var row = new TableRow();
            row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = string.Format(formatlink, pdr.Id, pdr.Product.NameProduct.ToString() ) }); 
tbody.Controls.Add(row); } `

` foreach (var cart in carts){
            txtCity.Text = cart.Product.NameProduct.ToString();
        }`
```